# simplecursoradapter not populated in setSingleChoiceItems AlertDialog

Tags: android, dialog, cursor

AlertDialog always show empty, here is the code when I pass String array instead of adapter its works but with adapter its empty. Am I missing something?

```
.Builder builder =   new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("Show dialog");
int selected =0; // select at 0


SimpleCursorAdapter Adapter =new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
            null, new String[]{"title","title2"}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1});

builder.setSingleChoiceItems(
        Adapter,
        selected ,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(
            DialogInterface dialog,
            int which) {

        Toast.makeText(
                MainActivity.this,
                "Select "+choiceList[which],
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply. I found your question while facing a similar issue. Why passing a cursorAdapter if you're not actually getting data from a database? I would simply create a new ArrayAdapter. Have you tried that?

```
ArrayAdapter<String> Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, new String[]{"title","title2"});
```

Note that I am using "android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice" instead of "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice", because your list is inside an AlertDialog. Hope this helps!

Tom.